# How to not hardcore my settings for my entity framework core database used by my generic host?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, console-application

While working with the generic host in .net core 2.2, I tried implementing a database project by creating a class that inherits from the DbContext class. So far so good. When I tried implementing the constructor for my Context like this:

```
public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

...and I try to create a migration by using

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

to actually build the database, it shows me the following error:

```
Unable to create an object of type 'NavisionServicesContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

I also tried defining the startup project with the --startup-project parameter but it doesn't work since I don't have a startup class for my generic host.

The only thing that's working is overriding the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext class. My Problem is that then I have to hardcode my connection string into that method like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog = TestDatabase; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true;");
}
```

And I haven't found a way to put that connection string into my settings file as I don't know how to use the IConfigurable inside my Context class.

How do I implement a correct database design pattern for my generic host in .netcore 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` to hold config values. And best thing about dotnet core is every functionality is split in different library giving flexibility to add only what is required.

First build a connection setting class to hold values

```
public class ConnectionSettings
{
    public string DefaultConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

And add configuration in config file as

```
{
  "connectionSettings": {
    "defaultConnectionString": "Here goes your connection setting"
  }
}
```

Now register this setting class in generic host builder as

```
IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configurationBuilder) =>
{
    // Assuming config file is configsettings.json
    configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("configsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
    // Using Environment variables as well to override any settings provided
    configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    // Command line args will be highest prioirty
    configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
})
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    IConfigurationSection config = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("connectionSettings");
    // Adding class to be part of Options
    services.Configure<ConnectionSettings>(config);
});
```

Now coming to DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private IOptions<ConnectionSettings> connectionSettingsOptions;
    public MyDbContext(IOptions<ConnectionSettings> connectionSettingsOptions)
    {
        this.connectionSettingsOptions = connectionSettingsOptions;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.connectionSettingsOptions.Value.DefaultConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Now this connection string can be overridden as per below priority 1 being lowest and 3 being highest because i added them in this order only while configuring generic host builder

1. Value from config file
2. Value from environment variables
3. Value from command line args passed as --connectionSettings:defaultConnectionString "myconnectionstring"

Nuget packages used

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.4)
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine (2.2.0)
3. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables (2.2.4)
4. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (2.2.0)
5. Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting (2.2.0)
6. Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions (2.2.0)

Hope this helps!!